# Intermodular communication in Oracle JET

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-jet, knockout-postbox

I have created a Sample application in Oracle JET using **Oracle JET QuickStart Basic template**. I want the application to have communication between two mudules. I have tried using the steps mentioned in Geertjan's blog [Intermodular communication in Oracle JET(Part 2)](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/intermodular-communication-in-oracle-jet-part-2) and [Intermodular communication in Oracle JET(Part 3)](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/intermodular-communication-in-oracle-jet-part-3) but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. It would be a great help if someone explain me how to do Intermodular communication using Oracle JET QuickStart Basic template. Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide any more details about what you have tried and what errors you are getting?  As you can tell from the blog posts you've read, there are multiple ways to do this.

Answer (score 2):

While navigating to other module you can pass some parameters.

```
<!-- Module binding with params -->
<div data-bind="ojModule: {name: currentName, params: currentName}"></div>
```

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jsdocs/ojModule.html

and variables can be initialized with parameters while module is attached

```
self.handleAttached = function (info) {
          var param = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(info.valueAccessor()).params;
          console.log(param);
          self.variableToBeInitialized= param;
          };
```

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/jet230/jet/reference-jet/oj.ModuleBinding.ConventionMethods.html

Comment: Include some of the code in your answer in case the links ever break

Answer (score 1):

You can use global variable which can be accessed/modified from all modules.

Step 1: Define variables(in appController.js/main.js) to be communicated across the modules.

```
self.var1= ko.observable("");
self.var2= ko.observable('');
```

Step 2: In modules you can access the variables after getting rootModel-

```
self.rootModel = ko.dataFor(document.getElementById('globalBody'));

var variable1= self.rootModel.var1;
var variable2= self.rootModel.var2;
```

Hope this helps!

Thanks